# Proving that a digraph with in degree and out degree equal for all vertices is Eulerian using maximum trails

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen lots of answers proving this theorem via induction. However, I'd like to know how to prove that every digraph such as all vertices have in degree equal to its out degree is Eulerian, using the concept of maximum trail.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: It sounds like an induction proof would be adaptable to the "maximum trail" framework. Can you give an example of an argument by induction so Readers can better appreciate the distinction?

Comment: As far as I understood, the induction technique would consist in, for instance, remove the edges from a cycle from the digraph; by the hypothesis, the remaining digraph is Eulerian, thus we can concatenate the tour with the cycle in a proper way to form an Eulerian tour in the original digraph. 

The "maximum trail", I believe, would be more close to the proof of the theorem unoriented version which uses the fact that a maximal trail is closed if the graph is even... Not sure if I made myself clear...